# JavaScript - Eliminate delay on text replacement

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a function in Javascript that changes some of the text that is displayed within the WordPress admin. The following code will add text to a h1 tag and add display none to some anchor tags. Issue I am having is that there is a 1-2 second where it shows the old text and the links are being displayed. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to eliminate this delay so the user has no idea that the text is being changed.

```
var replaceText = function() {
    var Wrapper = document.getElementById("wrap");

    var Header = Wrapper.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    Header[0].innerHTML = "Backup and Restore";

    var topLinks = Wrapper.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        topLinks[i].style.display = "none";
    }

}

function init(){
    replaceText();
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: If you are not concerned about `IE<9` then use `DOMContentLoaded` event to do such DOM manipulations..Or using `css` => `#wrap a{ display : none }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't eliminate the delay between them.

You are calling the init function after the window is loaded. This means your html and css are loaded first and upto that time the element you're trying to hide from javascript will not hide. So, you may stick with css solution to hide them and later when you want them to be displayed you may use javascript then.